# How would I add a class to this line of code?

Tags: php, html

I am working on my first ever project in php. I have a search that returns results, but anytime I add a class it does not work.

```
echo "<p><h3>".$results['COL 2']."</h3>".$results['COL 3']."</p>";
```

This code works fine. When I try to add a class that looks like this.

```
echo "<p><h3><span class="test">".$results['COL 2']."</span>     </h3>".$results['COL 3']."</p>";
```

It will not work, the return page is blank. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is with the quotes around your class. You start with `<p><h3><span class=`, but then you end your string. You should use single quotes (`'`) or escaped quotes (`\"`) around your class.

Answer (score 0):

Put class name in single quote:

```
echo "<p><h3><span class='test'>".$results['COL 2']."</span></h3>".$results['COL 3']."</p>";
```